# Proving pseudorandom generators

Tags: pseudo-random-generator

Can anyone please help me on how to prove or disprove (by counterexample) whether the following function $G'$ is a PRG (Pseudorandom Generator) given that $G$ is a PRG.

$$G'(s) = \operatorname{trunc}(G(\operatorname{trunc}(s))) \text,$$ where $\operatorname{trunc}(x)$ for a nonempty string $x$ denotes all but the last bit of $x$. (For this part, assume that $l(n) > n + 2$, and ignore the fact that $G'$ is undefined on input strings of length $1$.)

I've tried to think of an approach, but did not come up with anything.
I have some basic ideas like using hybrid arguments!

Comment: how your ideas proceed with hybrid arguments?

Comment: This question seems oddly familiar...

Comment: @ChrisPeikert I don't get this reference. Was it deleted & re-asked or something?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't help myself -- it's a homework question I assigned this week.

Comment: @ChrisPeikert There is a real problem with homework in my opinion. On the meta-site there is a discussion about this and the consensus is that homework doesn't need to be clearly tagged. I am very much against this, and would prefer if it was tagged and so I can know if I am helping someone truly interested or helping someone not do the work they are supposed to. In general, if I think that something "smells of homework", I don't answer.